# User Defined File Reading Function Causes NullPointerException Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file-io

I have to read some information from text file to different String arrays. So, I wrote a method for this task. Here is the code:

```
private String[] stateNames;
.
.
.
readHelper(stateNames);
.
.
.
private void readHelper( String[] str ) // str is stateNames
    {
        try
        {
            strLine = bufferReader.readLine();
            String[] tokens = strLine.split(",");
            str = new String[ tokens.length ];
            copyStr2Str(tokens, str);
            insertionSort( str ); // Everything is fine, str contains the data
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Generator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } // End of readHelper()
```

However after `readHelper()` is executed stateNames becomes `null`. I think, I cause some pointer errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, arguments are passed as a copy of the reference.

When you do,

```
str = new String[ tokens.length]
```

you discard the reference passed by the method call and create a new one (which only lives until the end of the `try` scope in which was created). The original `stateNames` keeps pointing to the original value, which was `null`.

Modify the method to return the `str` array and assign it to `stateNames`.

UPDATE to answer comment:

To understand this, try this code.

```
public class MyClass {
    private List<String> originalList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> originalList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void run() {
       this.test(originalList1, originalList2);
    }

    public void test(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
       list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
       list1.add(new String("Hello"));
       list2.add(new String("World"));
       System.out.println("list1.size -> " + list1.size());
       System.out.println("originalList1.size -> " + originalList1.size());
       System.out.println("list2.size -> " + list2.size());
       System.out.println("originalList2.size -> " + originalList2.size());
    }
  }
```

Since you assign a new object to list1, the original reference is lost so the original object is not affected (but with list2, you are still using the original object). Since in your code you create a new `String[]`, you no longer work in the original one.

Comment: Returning "str" won't cause a future "nullptrexception", right?

Answer (score 1):

You should return the array as a return value of the method.

```
private String[] readHelper()
    {
        String[] str = null;
        try
        {
            strLine = bufferReader.readLine();
            String[] tokens = strLine.split(",");
            str = new String[ tokens.length ];
            copyStr2Str(tokens, str);
            insertionSort( str ); // Everything is fine, str contains the data
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Generator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return str;
    } // End of readHelper()
```